# How to get the scope of bean which is autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have 2 beans one bean is Singleton and another one is prototype

```
 @Scope(value="singleton")
 @Component
 public class A{

 @Autowired
 B b;
 }
```

Another Bean,

```
 @Scope(value="prototype")
 @Component
 public class B{
 }
```

Through code i am able to get the bean scope of A and B separately,

```
 bean.getClass().getAnnotations(Scope.class)
```

How to get the scope of Bean B which has been autowired within A. Since A is a singleton, when i try to get the scope of B bean within A, should it also be a singleton..

not sure how to get that through code...

Comment: Please explain why you need this.

Comment: The scope will stil be `prototype` the scope of an injected bean won't suddenly change because it is injected into a differently scoped bean.

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry..One clarification..so a prototype bean which is within a singleton bean..will behave as singleton or prototype...?

Comment: That depends... If it is a scoped proxy it will behave as a prototype (each method will be invoked on a fresh instance) else it will be bound to the lifecycle of the singleton it is injected into. However each bean using an instance of the prototype scoped bean will get its own instance.